# Dynamics NAV could not load assembly or file

Tags: c#, dll, add-in, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I made a Class Library in C# which I use as an Add-In in Dynamics NAV to get the File Id of a file I have in Google Drive. For this I use the Google C# API.
When I run the code from Visual Studio I get no errors, but when I run it from RoleTailored Client, I get the following error:

> ### Microsoft Dynamics NAV
>
> A call to GoogleDriveAPI.Program.SetCredential failed with the following message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.9.2.27817, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I suppect it's because the .dll build of my class does not reference the .dll 'Google.Apis.Auth', but I am not sure.

Here is my code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GoogleDriveAPI
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
        private static string ApplicationName = "Google Drive Get FileID";
        private static UserCredential credential;
        private static string FileId;

        public void SetCredential(string credPath)
        {
            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }
        }



        public string GetFileId()
        {
            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.MaxResults = 1;

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Items;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var file in files) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Title, file.Id);
                    FileId = file.Id;
                }
                return FileId;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs doing the `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to identify the library that cannot be found. Filter the captured events by the process name and result code (it will be 'PATH NOT FOUND' referring to a path in the Nav add-ins folder).
Once you find the library, you can either copy it to the add-ins location or load it dynamically ([How to load assemblies into an application domain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39(v=vs.110).aspx)).